# Select a specific format date

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, datetime-format

I want to select a date column in specific format - suppose my date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`.  I want to select it as `dd/MMM/yyyy`

I can do this by:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), myDateColumn, 106)
```

The problem is that I want to select it as type `DATETIME`, not `VARCHAR` because I want to sort my grid on this column.

Comment: you can set display format on grid column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the formt of date in grid_ColumnAdded event

> e.Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format =
>   "dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy";

Answer (score 6):

If you want the column returned as a DATETIME then you can't convert it to a VARCHAR in the SQL - you'll need to set up the grid in which you're showing this date to display the column in the required format instead.

Answer (score 4):

Then don't convert it to VARCHAR to start with. Just select the column without any conversion, and it will come down to your C# client code as a `DateTime`.

Comment: But its format is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm.I want the formt dd/MMM/yyy

Comment: @Zain: A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format. You need to specify the format where you choose to convert it in the end.

Comment: Ok will you please tell me how to select a date column in specific  date format in ms sql.

Comment: @Zain: No, you're missing the point. You want to do the formatting as late as possible - on the *client*, not in SQL.

Comment: Is this not possible in ms sql query?

Comment: @Zain: I'm sure it is, but it wouldn't be a good idea. You should fetch the data *without* conversion, so you can do whatever you want to it more flexibly at the client - e.g. sorting by its value *as a date* and formatting independently of that.